# how to calculate sum (Total) of DataTable Columns using C#

Tags: c#

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("EmployeeId", typeof(int)),
        new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("Salary", typeof(int)) });
dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", 45000);
dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", 32000);
dt.Rows.Add(3, "Robert Schidner", 19000);
dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", 18500);
```

This is my table 
and i want to add salary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `dt.Compute` you can also use LINQ:

```
int sum = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Salary"));
```

The nice thing with LINQ is that it's so easy to calculate the everage instead:

```
double average = dt.AsEnumerable().Average(r => r.Field<int>("Salary"));
```

or to get max salary:

```
int maxSalary = dt.AsEnumerable().Max(r => r.Field<int>("Salary"));
```

or to filter, count all salaries which are higher than 3000:

```
int countHighSalary = dt.AsEnumerable().Count(r => r.Field<int>("Salary") >= 3000);
```

Answer (score 3):

The DataTable Compute function accepts two parameters
1. Expression – It is an Aggregate function such as SUM, COUNT, MIN, MAX and AVG.
2. Filter – It is used to filter rows like WHERE clause. If set blank then all rows are considered.

DataTable Compute without Filter expression
In the below example, Sum (Total) of Salary column of all employees is calculated using DataTable Compute function.
The Filter Expression is set Blank in order to calculate Sum (Total) of Salary column of all rows.

```
int sum = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("SUM(Salary)", string.Empty));
```

DataTable Compute with Filter expression
In the below example, Sum (Total) of Salary column of employees whose ID is greater than 2 is calculated using DataTable Compute function along with Filter expression.

```
int sum = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("SUM(Salary)", "EmployeeId > 2"));
```

Comment: `dt.Compute("SUM(Salary)", "EmployeeId > 2")` is good but I also want to put more clause along with `EmployeeId >2` like `Salary > 1000` so is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

So Simple Try This...

```
     double sum = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Compute("SUM(datatable_Column_Name)", string.Empty));
//Datatable Column Name Put Only
```