# C# Getting the sum of datagridview column by date

Tags: c#, system

How do I get the sum of the data in a datagridview by date. I'm doing a project which need to get the total sales from a specific date like to 5/13/2020 from 5/19/2020. I just need to get the total sum of sale from those days which is already in the table. thank you :).

this one lacks filtering of date range that I want

```
 conns.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblSales", conns);
            adapt.Fill(dt);
            sale.DataSource = dt;
            conns.Close();

            int sum = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("SUM(Total)", string.Empty));
            income.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);
```

[Click here to view the system image im doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEF3e.png)

Comment: Could you post some code you have tried so far?

Comment: all I can do right now is get the sum of everything in the table like this.        

  conns.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblSales", conns);
            adapt.Fill(dt);
            sale.DataSource = dt;
            conns.Close();

            int sum = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("SUM(Total)", string.Empty));
            reamount.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);

I still cant filter it by date range that I want haha sad

Comment: btw thanks bro its my first time asking here hehe :)

Comment: Welcome:) Please update the relevant code in the question. It's hard to understand in the comment.

Comment: I added a photo of the system im doing. so you can visualize what im trying to say thankssss alot

Comment: This is similar to the question: [DataTable need to sum a column with filter on it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39290521/3519108). What filters have you tried? Maybe try [DataTable.Compute.Filter remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.compute?view=netcore-3.1#remarks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should you use Linq Expression to **WhereClause** to filter by dates and **Sum** to get the total.

Sample code:
            //To simulate your DateTimePicker
            DateTimePicker dateTimePickerInit = new DateTimePicker();
            dateTimePickerInit.Value = new DateTime(2020, 03, 01);

```
        DateTimePicker dateTimePickerEnd = new DateTimePicker();
        dateTimePickerEnd.Value = DateTime.Now.Date;

        //To simulate your DataTable   
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("CompanySales");
        dt.Columns.Add("Company", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
        dt.Columns.Add("Total", typeof(decimal));

        //Sample of rows
        dt.Rows.Add("Company0", new DateTime(2020, 02, 01), 3000.2);
        dt.Rows.Add("Company1", new DateTime(2020, 03, 01), 4000.2);
        dt.Rows.Add("Company2", new DateTime(2020, 04, 01), 6000.2);
        dt.Rows.Add("Company3", new DateTime(2020, 05, 01), 7000.2);

        //The code of Linq expression WhereClause to filter and apply the results to another Datatable
        var dtFiltered = dt.AsEnumerable()
                             .Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Date").Date >= dateTimePickerInit.Value && x.Field<DateTime>("Date").Date <= dateTimePickerEnd.Value)
                             .CopyToDataTable();

        //The code of Linq expression to Apply Sum Total of the dtFiltered 
        var total = dtFiltered.AsEnumerable()
                             .Sum(x=> x.Field<decimal>("Total"));

        Console.WriteLine(total);
```

Comment: Thanks bro!!!. i still find this method confusing but i will try to understand more about this linq expression

Comment: Do you know how i will be able to filter the content of datatable using same concept of 2 different dates :).

Comment: What im able todo right now is filter it using string or like searching for the name of the person but what i need is to filter it using 2 dates in datepicker

Comment: Nathaniel, you can filter anything using x.Field<FieldType>("FieldName") in the WhereClause
x.Field access the fields in your DataTable.

Comment: var filtering = dt.AsEnumerable()
                        .Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Date")
   .Date >= dateTimePickerInit.Value && x.Field<DateTime("Date")
   .Date <= dateTimePickerEnd.Value));

how do I make this command filter the data table bro thankss

Comment: the first one works in getting the sum. but now how do I make it a command to update the details to filter it

Comment: To answer this i need more details of your datatable and code, what is "update details" for you? Should you add more infomration in the question?

Comment: how will i make the table display only the contents with the specified date ranges like
when I only want to see to 5/13/2020 from 5/19/2020 then the table will hide the other data which does not match the date. by using 2 datepicker and a single button to do the filter

Comment: Ok, you can use the method CopyToDatatable to apply the filter to a new Datatable, is import to keep the original Datatable with all registers (it will be the source for another filter).
I've added this to my sample.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to try something like the following.

```cs
string datesFilter = "theDate >= CONVERT('5/13/2020', 'System.DateTime')"
                     + " AND theDate <= CONVERT('5/19/2020', 'System.DaetTime')";

// if the data does not comply with the datesFilter, then null will be returned
object sumObject = dt.Compute("SUM(Total)", datesFilter);

int sum = 0;
if (sumObject != null)
{
    sum = Convert.ToInt32(sumObject);
}
```

[Microsoft Docs for DataColumn.Expression, CONVERT function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.8#functions)

[Microsoft Docs for DataTable.Compute, Filter remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.compute?view=netcore-3.1#remarks)

Comment: How does it work when selecting those dates will be in datepicker like in the photo

Comment: also it says System.Data.EvaluateException: 'Cannot perform '<=' operation on System.DateTime and System.Double.'

Comment: I updated my answer above.  The *filter* uses the DataColumn.Expression syntax. I included references to that syntax.  Unfortunately, the DataTable.Computer.Filter dates example is just plain wrong, but the remarks has a link to the DataColumn.Expression documentation.